# batch script to generate a list with file names newer than a saved date timestamp

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, informatica

I have a landing directory where we receive 10-15 files everyday. I then run a batch script to create a list with file names that have newly landed and then informatica reads the list of file names to process the new source files.

The problem here is, if a file is edited on same day after informatica loads the file. My batch script does not identify the updated file because the file has same date and name.

Is there a way to compare files based on timestamp and generate a file list? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
The current batch script code:

```
rem this batch script is used to list all the files hosted newly to a xyz landing directory
set LandingDir=\\path\to\landing\directory\*.csv

set DateFile=%sys_var%\script\DateFile.txt
set LastRunDateFile=%sys_var%\scripts\LastRunDateFile.txt
set Temp_File_List=%sys_var%\scripts\Temp_File_List.txt
set File_List=%sys_var%\SrcFiles\File_List.txt
set /P _PreviousDate=<%DateFile%
type %DateFile% > %LastRunDateFile%
xcopy "%LandingDir%" /l /s /d:%_PreviousDate% .>%Temp_File_List%
type %Temp_File_List% | findstr /v File(s)>%File_List%
echo %date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4% >%DateFile%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows there is the **archive** attribute always set on a file automatically if a file is modified in any way.

Using the archive file attribute makes the task much easier than storing last modification files times of all files processed and comparing last modification file times on next run.

All needed to be done is removing archive attribute on file being already processed, i.e. added to the file list.

Example:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "FilePattern=*.csv"
set "sys_var=C:\Temp\Test"
set "File_List=%sys_var%\SrcFiles\File_List.txt"
set "LandingDir=\\server\share\path\to\landing\directory"

if exist "%File_List%" del "%File_List%"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%LandingDir%\%FilePattern%" /AA-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    echo %LandingDir%\%%I>>"%File_List%"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -a "%LandingDir%\%%I"
)

if not exist "%File_List%" echo No new file!
endlocal
```

The command **DIR** returns because of `/AA-D` just **files** (not directories) with **archive** attribute set in **bare** format because of `/B`.

So output by **DIR** and processed by **FOR** are just the names of the files with archive attribute set without path and always without surrounding double quotes even if the file name contains a space or another special character.

The file names would be returned by **DIR** with full path on using additionally **DIR** option `/S` for listing recursively all files in specified directory and in all subdirectories matching the file pattern (and having archive attribute set).

Each file name is written into the file list file and then the archive attribute is removed from the file to ignore this file automatically on next run of the batch file except the archive attribute is set again because the file was modified in the meantime.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `attrib /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>>` and `2>nul` with escaping `>` with `^` to be interpreted on execution of **DIR** instead of **FOR**.